# Animation: Scaling Button to extend to top of screen

Tags: java, android, animation

I have a simple layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="My TextView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and on the click of this button, I am animating the TextView out of the top of the screen. I do so with this code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    TextView tv;
    Animation mSlideOutTop;
    Button button;
    boolean in = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        mSlideOutTop = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_out_top);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                in = true;
                tv.startAnimation(mSlideOutTop);
                tv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

where my animation is slide_out_top.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="600"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="-100%" />

</set>
```

So my problem is: as the TextView animates out of the screen, I need the button to expand to the top of the screen. Right now, the TextView animates away, and the space where it was, remains empty, like this:

[image]

Any ideas on how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish what you're trying to do, set the TextView's visibility to GONE at the conclusion of the slide-out animation. Something like:

```
tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Using GONE instead of INVISIBLE will have Android perform the layout operation as if the view didn't exist, and thankfully is the most easily reversible way to do what you're looking for - in other words, you can set it back to VISIBLE at some later point, and the button will return to its original size.

Then you just need to figure out a way to time that method call. One way is to put it inside a Runnable and call `Handler.postDelayed(theRunnable, 600);`, though personaly I prefer using ViewPropertyAnimators because you can assign them a Runnable to perform at their conclusion (call `ViewPropertyAnimator.withEndAction(theRunnable);` to do this) and it will figure it out for you.

Done this way, your animation code would look something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    // mSlideOutTop not used       

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            animateRemoval(v);
            in = true;

            // Do NOT set visibility to ANYTHING in here
        }
    });
}


private void animateRemoval(final View toRemove) {
    // The method .animate() creates a ViewPropertyAnimator.
    toRemove.animate()
            .setDuration(600)               // Previously defined in slide_out_top.xml
            .translationY(1000)             // Tweak this number to fit the direction/amplitude, I'm talking a wild guess
            .withEndAction(new Runnable() { // Stuff in here runs AFTER the animation.
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // It is critical that this method be executed AFTER the animation, because it 
                    // will cause a layout to occur, and executing layouts during animation is bad news bears.
                    toRemove.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your post. This answers half of my problem, but when I implement it this way, the Button "jumps" to the top when you set tv.setVisibility(View.GONE)...what I want it to do is gradually expand to the top as the TextView animates out, so it looks like the ListView is "pushing" the TextView off the screen (not sure if you get what I mean)

Comment: I think I get what you mean. The animation itself will probably be tricky to code on your own, but you might be able to get Android to do it for you for free if you set `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` in the XML definition of the view that contains the TextView and the Button. Give that a shot and see what happens.

Comment: Hm, it does work but it is very rough and laggy. The button expanding is delayed and the TextView text glitches

Comment: That sounds odd to me. If you did this correctly, the Button shouldn't be affected at all until the TextView isn't even visible anymore, so I don't know why it would glitch. Are you absolutely sure the `setVisibility()` call is not happening before the TextView animation finishes?

Comment: Actually, the button is fine, it is just the TextView that is glitches. I am setting the Visibility right after the aniimation starts. I will add an AnimationListener and set the visibility after it is done and see if that helps

Comment: This works only when I don't have an animation on the TextView. If I just toggle the TextView's visibility, the TextView fades in and out, and the Button stretches as it should. The glitching problems arises when I have an animation on the TextView. Not sure why it would do that...

Comment: I've added some extra code to my answer to clarify things. Try that and see what happens. I think you might still be setting visibility before the animation is done - otherwise, there shouldn't be any reason the animation should be affected. If the code I added doesn't help, please add any changes you've made to the original question.

Comment: It is working for the most part, I will tweak it still. Thanks for the help. One last thing: do you know if I can change the speed at which the Button expands after I set the TV to GONE?